import csv into postgresql column varchar but data in scientific format
I imported a CSV file into postgresql and unfortunately i got the data in scientific format despite the fact that the respective postgresql column type is varchar using the
following method via pgadmin 4
https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/8.7/import_export_data.html
Any idea how can i convert it back into the pre-imported data value via a specific function or is it impossible?

Regards

That is not Postgres. It is either the client you are using to view the data or the client/software you used to import the data. Add the information as to what client you are using and the method you used to do the import as text update to the question text.

Use psql to look at the data, I'm pretty sure you will see that is has not been changed. I am equally sure that this is something pgAdmin is doing for display purposes.

Using pgAdmin4 8.9 I could not replicate this. I entered '52345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890' into a varchar field and that is what I saw in the query results.

You can turn it back again to number like this:
select cast('5.63875752953081E+019' as numeric);

or to varchar adding ::varchar at the end of cast function



numeric




56387575295308100000



